# I can't create new build definitions on TFS Online

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I use TFS online to store my source codes, and I want to use the integrated build service.

I have created several Build définitions last week, and they work perfectly (I can start builds, modify them). But since this morning, I can't create new Build définitions. Visual Studio show me an error message :

Could not find service '0000000d-0000-8888-8000-000000000000' from host'7e427fe9-b401-40e8-b6c8-5613d886b8df'. Please ensure the service is registered with the Shared Platform Service.

When I start Fiddler, I see an error 500 when calling the service : /DefaultCollection/Services/v3.0/SecurityService.asmx - There is a "ServiceOwnerNotFoundException".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <soap:Code>
                <soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value>
                <soap:Subcode>
                    <soap:Value>ServiceOwnerNotFoundException</soap:Value>
                </soap:Subcode>
            </soap:Code>
            <soap:Reason>
                <soap:Text xml:lang="en">Could not find service '0000000d-0000-8888-8000-000000000000' from host'7e427fe9-b401-40e8-b6c8-5613d886b8df'. Please ensure the service is registered with the Shared Platform Service.</soap:Text>
            </soap:Reason>
            <soap:Detail />
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I can't find anything about this problem, do you have any idea ?

Comment: There's nothing showing at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsoservice/ indicating a problem. I wonder if there's a deployment of some sort happening in preparation for the \\BUILD conference and whether this is temporary problem. For reference I just created a new build definition, and it all worked OK.  If the problem continues, contact support https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/cloud-services-assisted-support-vs

Comment: We're seeing this same error in our 3rd party application which talks to TFS, although only on the Europe datacenter- the South Central US one seems OK.

Comment: Also, neither the basic or premium contact support links work for me in chrome or IE...

Comment: I am also on the european datacenter. The contact support worked for me, I sent a message, I will update this post when I receive an answer

Comment: Getting this error with a git repo hosted on visual studio online.

Comment: My repository is in South Central US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have rolled out the fix for this issue. Sorry for the disruption!

Comment: We also have this issue, we cannot create any new build definitions at the moment. We do not get a detailed error message, just a dialog saying 'Team Foundation Error: One or more errors occurred'. This is a major project since we have just started a new branch for a project and cannot build it. Do you know of any further service problems?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is identified and a fix is on the way - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsoservice/archive/2015/04/27/issues-with-visual-studio-online-4-27-investigating.aspx